# Trouble loading Bloomberg addins on excel using python

Tags: python, win32com, bloomberg

I am trying to open an excel which is connected to BBG and refresh values.

To open an instance of excel and load bloomberg addins, I used a solution from the attached link a while ago 
[Python using win32com wont update excel sheet with needed Add-ins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57714123/python-using-win32com-wont-update-excel-sheet-with-needed-add-ins)

The solution worked fine for me till yday when for some reason `xlapp.RegisterXLL('C:/blp/API/Office Tools/bofaddin.dll')` is giving me trouble. i.e. not loading and crashing my codes.

Anyone has any ideas whats happening?

Codes are below if anyone interested

```
import os, os.path
import win32com.client

xlapp = win32com.client.DispatchEx("Excel.Application")
xlapp.RegisterXLL('C:/blp/API/Office Tools/bofaddin.dll')
xlapp.Workbooks.Open('C:\\blp\\API\\Office Tools\\BloombergUI.xla')
wb = xlapp.Workbooks.Open(filepath,None,False)
xlapp.Visible = True
wb_addin = ('C:/blp/API/Office Tools/bofaddin.dll')
wb.RefreshAll()
```

Answer (score 0):

Try importing time and putting time.sleep(2) after each command.  I found the Bloomberg links sometimes need a second to update.

```
xlapp = win32com.client.DispatchEx("Excel.Application")
time.sleep(2)
xlapp.RegisterXLL('C:/blp/API/Office Tools/bofaddin.dll')
time.sleep(2)
xlapp.Workbooks.Open('C:\\blp\\API\\Office Tools\\BloombergUI.xla')
time.sleep(2)
wb = xlapp.Workbooks.Open(filepath,None,False)
xlapp.Visible = True
wb_addin = ('C:/blp/API/Office Tools/bofaddin.dll')
```

Comment: thanks @GoPackGo, what solved my problem was loading BloombergUI.xla before the xlapp.RegisterXLL('C:/blp/API/Office Tools/bofaddin.dll'). For some reason since then its working absolutely fine.